# MPMoviePlayerController plays video but shows black screen in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am using the MPMoviePlayerController to play video stored in main bundle.
However **sometime** when I play video it plays the video but shows the **black screen** in that case seek bar also works properly. 
At that time if I switch to fullscreen mode and get back to normal mode(or send app in background mode and bring it in foreground mode) then it plays(resumes) video properly(did not show the black screen).

Please refer the below screenshot of an App:[image]

**UPDATE:**

Below is the code used to play video:

```
- (void)playVideo:(NSString *)filepath {

    NSLog(@"get audiosession");
    AVAudioSession *audiosession =     [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audiosession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil ];
    NSLog(@"finish audiosession");
    appDelegate.currentCourseNoExt = [filepath stringByDeletingPathExtension];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3",appDelegate.currentCourseNoExt]];
    NSError *error;
    NSLog(@"get avaudioplayer");
    AVAudioPlayer *avPlayerTemp = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                                   initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                   error:&error];
    NSLog(@"finish avaudioplayer");

    avPlayer = avPlayerTemp;
    NSLog(@"copy avaudioplayer");

    // get frame
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size.height -= 0;
    NSLog(@"self.view.frame - %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));

    appDelegate.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath]];
    appDelegate.moviePlayer.view.frame = frame;
    appDelegate.moviePlayer.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    [self.view addSubview:appDelegate.moviePlayer.view];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:(appDelegate.moviePlayer.view)];

    imgBottomAdvertisement.frame = CGRectMake(0, appDelegate.moviePlayer.view.frame.size.height - imgBottomAdvertisement.frame.size.height, imgBottomAdvertisement.frame.size.width, imgBottomAdvertisement.frame.size.height);
    [appDelegate.moviePlayer.backgroundView addSubview:imgBottomAdvertisement];

    appDelegate.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackRate= 1.0;
    appDelegate.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime =  appDelegate.SMile.doubleValue;

    [avPlayer setRate:0];

    [appDelegate.moviePlayer play ];
    [avPlayer play];
}
```

The above method is called from viewDidAppear method of ViewController.